Why can Ruby apparently not find the Capistrano current directory?
Several RoR web apps have been running on a server for years and been regularly updated with the latest versions of ruby, rails and mod_passenger. Now, suddenly one particular app (none of the other apps, even though they are using an identical setup) has developed the problem described below.
I'm on Alma Linux 8.10 currently with Apache 2.4.37, mod_passenger 6.0.23, ruby 3.3.3 via rbenv and rails 7.2.1. Deployment is via capistrano 3.19.1 and capistrano-passenger 0.2.1.
Here's the (abbreviated) error message in /var/log/httpd/error_log which happens when I first try to access the app in a browser after deployment:
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /var/www/me.mio/current (LoadError)
[...age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/me.mio/current: The application process exited prematurely.

age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:284 ]: Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred.

At the moment (thanks to comments by engineersmnky) the interpretation of this error message is that ruby thinks the capistrano current directory does not exist.
Here's some relevant lines from the /etc/httpd/conf.d file:
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  PassengerRuby /home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  PassengerMinInstances 1
  ...
</VirtualHost>

PassengerPreStart https://...

Here's the result of running some commands in the app's current directory, which does exist:
$ cat .ruby-version # 3.3.3
$ rbenv version # 3.3.3 (set by /var/www/me.mio/current/.ruby-version)
$ ruby -v # ruby 3.3.3 ...
$ which ruby # ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ rbenv rehash # doesn't help
$ ls -l ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ... 217824 Jun 13 19:00 /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby
$ ~/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby -v # ruby 3.3.3 ...

Finally, here is the output from passenger-status. Note that the difference between the me.mio app (the one with the problem) and the others.
Version : 6.0.23
Date    : 2024-09-03 10:39:24 +0000
Instance: LEqbzjUQ (Apache/2.4.37 (AlmaLinux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k Phusion_Passenger/6.0.23)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 5
Processes     : 4
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/www/me.mio/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/me.mio/current
  Requests in queue: 0

/var/www/smd/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/smd/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 128934   Sessions: 0       Processed: 7       Uptime: 1h 15m 50s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 78M     Last used: 3m 35s

/var/www/wd/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/wd/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 129234   Sessions: 0       Processed: 11      Uptime: 1h 15m 45s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 77M     Last used: 13m 40s

/var/www/me.hou/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/me.hou/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 139227   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 16m 15s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 68M     Last used: 16m 15s ag

/var/www/me.sta/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/me.sta/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 132177   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 56m 53s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 52M     Last used: 56m 53s ag

There is no useful information in the /tmp/.../passenger-error-*.html file generated by passenger.
Does anyone have any ideas or suggest how to investigate further?

It is not saying ruby doesn't exist it is saying the directory "/var/www/me.mio/current" does not exist. Ar you certain the directory exists and has the correct permissions?

Thanks for commenting. Yes, that exists, created by capistrano during deployment and where I ran things like which ruby as noted above. Permissions and ownership look normal (same as all the working apps).

Well it appears passenger disagrees because that is what the error is stating. Maybe double check your spelling and reboot passenger or apache? The error comes from ruby (and the correct version you are expecting) so the question should be rephrased or deleted and a new question started. In other words this /home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.3.3/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- Passenger AppPreloader: /var/www/me.mio/current (LoadError) is ruby telling you it cannot find that directory.

When capistrano deploys, it creates a symlink between current and the most recent release. I have experienced issues with puma (using puma as an example here, I realize it is not directly related to your problem) pointing at the incorrect current directory because it gets set when puma boots. Therefore, if I deployed but DID NOT restart puma after deploying, current in the puma config would actually be pointing at the previous release. Can you confirm that there are no issues with the related current symlink?

Thanks Jacob. I thinks it looks normal. To check, I just did another deploy and Capistrano told me deployed as release 20240905215616 then I looked on the server and that is the last of the 6 directories in releases and what current is now pointing at. Sadly, the app is still broken with the same error message.

Also, a subsequent cap production passenger:restart did not help.

However, after a cap production doctor, it was evident that Rubygems (version 3.5.17) and Bundler (version 2.5.11) were out of sync and I knew Bundler 2.5.17 was installed on both the local machine and server. So I deleted the Bundled with 2.5.11 from Gemfile.lock, did a bundle update (which updated that to 2.5.17), committed and deployed. And guess what? It worked!

I am so relieved! Thank you both for your comments, you helped me blunder into the solution.

The versions of Rubygems (3.5.17) and Bundler (2.5.11) had got out of sync. This did not affect development tests but caused a problem when deployed.
Deleting the version of bundler in Gemfile.lock, running bundle update (so bundler is now 2.5.17), committing and redeploying fixed it.
One way to help notice the out of sync versions is to run bin/cap production doctor (or bundle exec cap production doctor).
